# Why is sorted() not sorting my list of strings?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

**Problem:**

So I was trying to *alphabetically* sort my list of strings maybe I overlooked something very minor. I have tried both .sort and sorted() but maybe I didn't do it correctly?

Here is my Code:

```
words = input("Words: ")
list1 = []
list1.append(words.split())
print(sorted(list1))
```

**Expected output**-

```
Input: "a b d c"
Output: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

**Current output**-

```
Input: "a b d c" 
Output: [['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']]
```

Comment: I'm not new to coding but I sometimes forget minor things like this and turtle stuff :d. Forget me for being dumb lol

Comment: your output is a list of list,Output: [["a" "b" "c" "d"]]..make output = ['a', 'b', 'c']..then sorted?

Comment: list.append will add the entire argument to the data (It doesn't add each element to the end of the list). So your list will be [ ["one", "two", "three" , "four"] ] . Try `list1.extend(words.split())`

Comment: I was wondering why there was two sets of square brackets... no wonder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are trying to sort a list inside a list.

When you call `words.split()` it returns a `list`. So when you do `list1.append(words.split())` it is appending a list into `list1`.

You should do this:

```
words = input("Words: ")

list1 = words.split()

print(sorted(list1))
```

Comment: Glad to help :) Feel free to ask anything that I didn't explain

Answer (score 1):

You can try a simple method as follows:

```
list1 = [i for i in input('Words: ').split(' ')]
print(sorted(list1))
```

I've tested it. And it is working

Comment: `.split()` method splits the characters and it makes into a list. So when you append it, a list ([a,d,b,c]) is appended to **list1**. So that's the reason it is not sorted , if you try `sorted(list1[0])`, your code would work.

Answer (score 0):

Without deviating from your current effort, the only modification you need to do to fix your code is :

```
words = input("Words: ")
list1 = []
list1.append(words.split())
print(sorted(list1[0]))
```

**Explanation of what you were doing wrong:**

*The root cause of your confusion is **`append()`** .According to [python docs](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_append.asp),**`append()`** takes exactly one argument.*

So when you do this,

```
words.split()
```

You are trying to append more than 1 element into the `list1` and when you ***`append()`*** something more than 1 in a list, *it appends as a nested list (i.e a list inside another list.)*

To support my explanation you can see that your code fixed by a simple `[0]`

```
print(sorted(list1[0]))
```

That is because your input is stored as a list of list, AND it is stored in the first index (Point to note - 1st index in a python list is 0, hence the usage of `list1[0]`)

*Please let me know if I could have explained it in a more simpler way or if you have any other confusions that aid from the above explanation.*